# Laravel 8 Relations and Pivot Tables...can only select related row that has value same as primary, help understanding what im doing wrong please

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

I have a page controller which is used to control what template/view is displayed based on the URI requested. If the URI matches the 'slug' field in the Database then the controller serves up the related template/view that is associated with that page.

There are separate Pages Model and Templates Model that are related via the page_id primary key.

The templates table has primary key of template_id.

The Pivot table of: page_templates,  has two fields: primary_id and templates_id.

It seems to be that this pivot table only likes when both the page_id and template_id are the same. When what need is for the template_id to be independent.

What im trying to achieve is that when i request a page_id the related template_id is used to select the correct template view.

At the moment this only works if the page_id and template_id have the same value ie page_id = 7....template_id = 7. I would like to be abe to change the template_id to a value that is not the same as the page_id but this triggers the abort(401) call.

Here is the controller

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function GetPage(Request $request)
    {
         $uri = $request->path();

         $id = Pages::query()
             ->where('slug', '=', $uri)
             ->first();


        $page = Pages::with('categories', 'templates', 'media', 'metadata')
            ->where('page_id', '=', $id->page_id)
            ->first();


         if ($uri == $id->slug) {
             return view($page->templates[0]->name, compact('page'));
         }
         else {
             abort(404);
         }

    }
```

Here is a sample of the models...

```
class Pages extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'page_id';

    /*  public function metadata()
     {
         return $this->hasOne(Metadata::class );
     }
    */

    public function templates()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Templates::class, 'page_templates', 'template_id', 'page_id');
    }
}
```

and..

```
class Templates extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'template_id';

    public function pages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Pages::class, 'page_id', 'page_id');
    }
}
```

I welcome any advice and assistance that anyone has, and as you can tell i am new to this so please go easy !

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reverse relation in the template model also currently you are missing to add many to many relationship add the following thing in your templates model

```
 public function pages()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Pages::class, 'page_templates', 'page_id', 'template_id');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relation is defined the wrong way around; As per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure), the third parameter should reference the model from which you define the relation, and the fourth the related model. You have defined them vice versa. This doesn't throw any errors, you'll just never get results.

```php
public function templates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Templates::class, 'page_templates', 'page_id', 'template_id');
}
```